# How to find shortest connections between all the points?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dictionary, path

There's 2d array, with points marked on it - just like in the first picture. What I have to do, is to find connection between all the points on that map (so you can travel from any point to all other points). Sum of length of all edges has to be possibly smallest.

[image]

Input:

```
(0, 0) (5, 5) (5, 1) (4, 4) (1, 5) (2, 4) (2, 1) // 1st,2nd,3rd city ...
```

Output:

```
1-7, 7-3, 7-6, 6-5, 6-4, 4-2
```

Comment: This looks a lot like a [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Comment: Treat your input set of points as a fully connected graph, with the distance between a pair of points as the edge weight.  Then find the minimum spanning tree of the graph.

Comment: For more info on the spanning tree problem see for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat your input set of points as a fully connected graph, with the distance between a pair of points as the edge weight. Then find the minimum spanning tree of the graph.

Kruskal's algorithm is particularly easy:

- Start with no edges in your output graph.
- Go through each edge of your input graph in order of weight, smallest first.

  - If the two vertices aren't already part of the same tree in your output graph, then add the edge to your output graph.

There are various techniques you can use to make this very fast if speed is an issue.